# Android: adb: Permission Denied

Tags: android, adb

Whatever I type after `adb shell` it fails with `Permission denied`:

```
D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb shell find /data -name *.db
find: permission denied

D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb shell test
test: permission denied

D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb remount
remount failed: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you trying to run the adb shell, in emulator or target device; if on target device you cant access the /data folder until unless you have root permission.

Comment: after `adb root` >> `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`
what to do?

Comment: I guess you need a rooted phone to be able to run that

Comment: yes, I know. But, as you see currently I do not have the reputation to comment the Author's post, but i had this problem, so the only way was to add new post, or to open duplicate thread, so I decided to add a post.

Comment: the phone is was rooted, but something went wrong with the OS. It was freezing after loading the home screen on reboot. Anyway - nandroid flashing the phone with the stock ROM solved the problem.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

According to `adb help`:

```
adb root                     - restarts the adbd daemon with root permissions
```

Which indeed resolved the issue for me.

Comment: You'll also need to enable root access for adb if you haven't done so already -- see @Macarse's answer.

Comment: This is not true. You just have to switch to the correct user. See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38292436/342947

Comment: I'm getting `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`

Answer (score 65):

**Without rooting**: If you can't root your phone, use the `run-as <package>` command to be able to access data of your application.

Example:

> `$ adb exec-out run-as com.yourcompany.app ls -R /data/data/com.yourcompany.app/`

`exec-out` executes the command without starting a shell and mangling the output.

Comment: This only works for apps built to be debuggable - ie, you can use it for apps you are developing but it should not work for production releases of your app, or anyone else's apps.

Comment: This returns `run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted` for me

Comment: It works for emulator API 29, and don't forget to put `.debug` prefix to the end of app's package for debug apps:

Comment: I'm receiving: `run-as: package not an application: com.android.phone`

Answer (score 26):

The reason for "permission denied" is because your Android machine has not been correctly rooted. Did you see `$` after you started `adb shell`? If you correctly rooted your machine, you would have seen `#` instead.

If you see the `$`, try entering Super User mode by typing `su`. If Root is enabled, you will see the `#` - without asking for password.

Comment: Once you have correctly rooted your machine, you will need to have enabled adb root access and be running adb in root mode before your `su` step can work - see @Macarse's and @Roman's answers.

Comment: No.  The reason for "permission denied" is that there is no `find` command.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You saved my life, I was also writting shell command from inside the adb shell already

Comment: I'm trying to see files in the Android simulator.  I type 'su' after the '$' and it says: su: not found

Comment: Nothing in the question mentions a rooted device. Why does this answer require the device to be rooted?

Answer (score 7):

None of the previous solutions worked for me but I was able to make it work using this command

```
adb shell "run-as com.yourcompany.app cat /data/data/com.yourcompany.app/shared_prefs/SHARED_PREF_PROTECTED.xml" > SHARED_PREF_PROTECTED.xml
```

Comment: This is great, however for binary files such as images or localDBs, the encoding seems to change. How would one copy binary files to windows?

Comment: This only works if the app is debuggable

Answer (score 6):

You might need to activate adb root from the developer settings menu.
If you run `adb root` from the cmd line you can get:

```
root access is disabled by system setting - enable in settings -> development options
```

Once you activate the root option (ADB only or Apps and ADB) adb will restart and you will be able to use root from the cmd line.

Comment: If you can't see the 'Developer options' item in your Settings menu, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16866430/647939) for details of how to make it visible.  (In short: Settings > About phone > Build number > Tap 7 times(!).)

Comment: But once in, I don't see anything here! What should it say?

Comment: **This option does not exist in stock Android builds** - if it exists at all, it would be confined to someone's aftermarket ROM.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a GUI? I would guess there is an option for it in `/system/build.prop`, but I can't find it.

Comment: Where do I find the menu to look for settings?

Answer (score 5):

The `data` partition is not accessible for non-root users, if you want to access it you must root your phone.

`ADB root` does not work for all product and depend on phone build type.

in the new version of android studio, you can explore `/data/data` path for debuggable apps.

##### update 2022

Android Studio new versions have some tools like `Device Explorer` and `App Inspection` to access application data. (app must be debuggable).

Comment: Confirm the```permission denied``` on Android emulator with API 30. I was working on getting on disk a sqlite file via ```$adb pull``` which also requires ```adb root```

Comment: you cannot directly access to data folder or DB location from ADB in non-rooted device. but you can use Android Studio tools like Device Explorer or App Inspection to access debuggable app data like SQLite DB.

Comment: `Device Explorer` worked for me, in Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1) . I found my application files in `/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files`. I think this it equivalent to `adb run-as` because for other apps at the same level if I try to open the folder I get an error `run-as ...`.

Comment: The app is built with Debug. The phone is a Nokia with Android 11 Go and not rooted (and not rootable, as with most modern phones.)

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to get /data/anr/ as I was, you can use an easy approach

```
adb bugreport
```

source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72416665/11793333)

Answer (score -4):

Do adb remount. And then try adb shell

Comment: `adb remount` gives: `remount failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: No.  This has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score -5):

Solution for me was (thx to [David Ljung Madison post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271878/android-adbd-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds))

1. Root the phone & be sure it is rooted
2. Adb server (adbd) was not run as root so [downloaded & installed the adbd insecure app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590)
3. Restart adb `adb kill-server`
4. Run it & worked like a flower!

Answer (score -8):

Run your `cmd` as administrator this will solve my issues.
Thanks.

Comment: No.  The question concerns a refusal from Android, not from Windows.