# Navigation in device via ADB

Tags: android, cmd, adb

Novice question really- is there a way to navigate and view all of the directories/files on a android device via the ADB? I can successfully run the ADB but I'm struggling with navigating in the device. I'm looking for commands similar to `dir` or `cd` in the normal cmd, because they don't seem to work.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you type `adb` you will see all available commands.

For example, to open a shell of the only device connected via USB you can type:

```
adb -d shell
```

In that shell you can navigate on your device, BUT not with Windows commands of course, you will have to use Unix commands (`dir` would be `ls` for example). For a list of all available shell-commands type `ls /system/bin` from within your shell, or `adb shell ls /system/bin` in your windows terminal.

In order to download files from your device you can use `adb pull` in your normal cmd terminal, for uploading `adb push`.

If you get "permission denied" errors [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399028/android-adb-permission-denied). Keep in mind though that some folders are not accessible for security reasons. You would have to root your phone to access those.

Comment: The `-d` means "use USB device (error if multiple devices connected". (From the top of output from `adb help`). To specify a device, use `adb -s <device identifier> shell`.