# FileObserver on system files

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-permissions

For a survey I want to monitor user-compelled changes in the Android M application permission settings.

I decided to create a FileObserver watching `/data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml`. This file holds all information but only has read/write access for the system `-rw-------`. `chmod` won't work because access privileges are restored on every change. So my monitoring app needs system permissions.

I followed this method to [deploy my app directly to priv-app directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302833/how-to-install-an-app-in-system-app-while-developing-from-android-studio). Works like a charm, app is considered a system app, but still does not have permission to read the above-mentioned file. `File.canRead()` fails just as `File.exists()`.

Is there maybe something I have to add in the AndroidManifest.xml to make it work, or is making use of the priv-app folder a complete wrong guess? Do I have to sign the application? For final deployment I wanted to add the application to a custom rom using some kind of kitchen.