# Access localhost on laravel valet from Android emulator

Tags: android, laravel, macos-sierra, laravel-valet

I'm using laravel valet to serve an API on a Mac. How can you access it from an Android emulator

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the /etc/hosts file on your Android Emulator following the instructions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47622017/700439).
2. Add the following to this file:

```
myapp.test  10.0.2.2
```

This will route requests made to `myapp.test` to `10.0.2.2`, which is a static IP address that an AVD uses instead of `localhost` to access the host.

Answer (score 0):

As the Android Emulator is different computer than your Mac, you should use the IP address of the Mac (or its name if it is resolved on your network) instead of localhost.

For example if your Mac has IP address `192.168.1.10`, then use this address.

Comment: Even if i use the IP of the Mac it gives a message "Valet - 404 Not Found"

Comment: If you receive a 404, you probably getting the web server at the wrong URL. Check it.

Comment: I don't know why it is downvoted. This is also a solution with a proper explanation. Also if you receive Valet - 404 Not Found, it means you already have connected.