# android emulator sdk 10 api 29 won't start after remount and reboot

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-debug

I'm running into strange behaviour when trying to remount device with SDK 10 and API 29, after the remount the emulator hang (device offline)
**To reproduce:**

- OS: MacOs
- Using android studio define new device: pixel 2 (or pixel 3/nexus 5), Android 10.0 x86, API 29
- start the emulator using command line: `emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29_SDK10 -writable-system -verbose`
- run `adb -s emulator-5554 root`
- run `adb -s emulator-5554 remount`

```
The adb remmount result failure as follow:
adb remount 
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
W Disabling verity for /system
E Skipping /system
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
W DM_DEV_STATUS failed for scratch: No such device or address
E [liblp]No device named scratch
[liblp]Partition scratch will resize from 0 bytes to 536870912 bytes
[liblp]Updated logical partition table at slot 0 on device /dev/block/by-name/super
[libfs_mgr]Created logical partition scratch on device /dev/block/dm-3
[libfs_mgr]__mount(source=/dev/block/dm-3,target=/mnt/scratch,type=f2fs)=0: Success
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Using overlayfs for /vendor
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
[libfs_mgr]__mount(source=overlay,target=/vendor,type=overlay,upperdir=/mnt/scratch/overlay/vendor/upper)=0
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
/system/bin/remount exited with status 7
remount failed
```

- run: `adb -s emulator-5554 reboot`
  the `adb reboot` cause the emulator to hang

```
➜  ~ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is adb remount broken on android api 29?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010655/is-adb-remount-broken-on-android-api-29)

Answer (score 17):

I succeded with

```
adb root
adb shell avbctl disable-verification
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
```

Comment: If it's not working, run emulator with -writable-system.