# Android emulator stuck on reboot after `adb disable-verity` or `adb remount`

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to enable write access to an android emulator in order to modify its `hosts` file but I can't get it working. Whenever the adb command (`remount` or `disable-verity`) ran successfully the `reboot` command makes the emulator hangs. Without executing these commands, the `reboot` command works as expected. Can someone help me fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem and solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867956/android-emulator-sdk-10-api-29-wont-start-after-remount-and-reboot) solved it:

```
adb root
adb shell avbctl disable-verification
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
```