# [Android.Emulator].Cannot push files into /system folder on Android Q and R

Tags: android, emulation, offline, readonly

I need to push files into the emulator of AndroidQ or AndroidR /system directory, I tried almost all of the methods, but it couldn't work.

**on AndroidQ**
I can add "-writable-system" to follow emulator command, then ADB root + remount (remount exit with errors), eventually, I can push files to /system folder, but if I reboot this emulator, it will be always at offline status, and UI of emulator always keeps black. Only after I delete all *.img files under the avd directory, an emulator can work again.

**on AndroidR**
I can execute  or  without errors return. And it will prompt me to reboot, once I reboot, the emulator will always keep offline state. Till now, on the AndroidR emulator, I haven't entered into /system directory yet.

Does anyone have any suggestions? thanks a lot.

[Someone else meets this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010655/is-adb-remount-broken-on-android-api-29)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is adb remount broken on android api 29?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010655/is-adb-remount-broken-on-android-api-29)

Comment: @NoobTW my question is duplicated with your link, that link also has no anwser.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I use emulator based on AOSP, it works fine.