# How Do I Make System Writeable in Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, root

I want to be able to write to `/system` in my Android Studio Emulator. I've made sure to use a rootable, non-Google Play Services AVD. I'm currently using the Pixel 2 - API 28 AVD (targets Android 9.0).

I've made sure to run `adb root` and that works, though `adb remount` gives `remount of the / superblock failed: Permission denied` as an error. (I also tried running `adb disable-verity` and rebooting before remounting, but I still get the same remount error.)

I've tried `adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system`, but I get `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts`.

I've also tried

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

but get the same `mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts` error

(I've tried it without `/system` too. It appears to work, but if I then try to write to `/system`, I get `mv: /system: Read-only file system`)

I've tried `emulator -avd -writeable-system` but I get `'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Can someone please help me figure out how to run the emulator in such a way that I can write to `/system`?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows open a command prompt/power shell in `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools` and execute

```
.\emulator.exe -writable-system -avd Pixel_2_API_28
```

In another command prompt/power shell in  `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` execute

```
.\adb.exe remount
```

On Linux you can use the the following commands:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -writable-system -avd Pixel_2_API_28
adb remount
```

Comment: Actually to do remount follow these steps:  
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/64989222/4605937]