# Why does adb remount fail?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-tv

When I enter `adb remount` the terminal responds with

> Skip mounting partition: /product

> Skip mounting partition: /product_services

> W DM_DEV_STATUS failed for scratch: No such device or address E

> [liblp]No device named scratch

> [liblp]Partition scratch will resize from 0 bytes to 814587904 bytes

> [liblp]Updated logical partition table at slot 0 on device /dev/block/by-name/super

> [libfs_mgr]Created logical partition scratch on device /dev/block/dm-3

> [libfs_mgr]__mount(source=/dev/block/dm-3,target=/mnt/scratch,type=f2fs)=0:

> Success

> Skip mounting partition: /product

> Skip mounting partition: /product_services

> [libfs_mgr]__mount(source=overlay,target=/vendor,type=overlay,upperdir=/mnt/scratch/overlay/vendor/upper)=0
> Skip mounting partition: /product Skip mounting partition:
> /product_services

> /system/bin/remount exited with status 7 remount

> failed

[image]

**Why is adb remount failing here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
```

and after reboot

```
adb root
adb remount
```

This can get a bit tricky because of the reboot. You might find this post relevant: [Is adb remount broken on android api 29?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010655/is-adb-remount-broken-on-android-api-29)

Answer (score 0):

Your Tv emulator is user build which means adb root is disabled in that build, while your other emulator is userdebug build means it has adb root enabled, here is more details about [builds](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#build-variants) so in order to enable root in your tv emulator you need to root it. [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171442/root-android-virtual-device-with-android-7-1-1) is some info about rooting emulator.
If you can root your tv emulator then it you can run adb shell & su commands to remount it in read/write mode.