# Cannot install a system level certificate in Android 14, using the same method that works on Android 13

Tags: android, android-emulator

As part of my automated testing, I want to see all requests and responses that our app does, so I install a proxy certificate in Android Emulator at User level, and use adb commands to then move it to 'system/etc/security/cacerts'. This will enable me to see all https requests sent by my app.

The above method has been working fine till Android 13. However the same does not work on Android 14. Has anyone else faced the same issue

Comment: For context this is the method that works on Android 13 and below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010655/is-adb-remount-broken-on-android-api-29

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76007110/android-14-upsidedowncake-doesnt-see-certificate-installed-in-system-etc-sec