# Android adb mount:permission denied

Tags: android, shell, permissions

I'm trying to edit my system/etc/hosts using adb as per this answer https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file

But when I try to run adb mount I always get permission denied

C:\Windows\System32>adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system
mount: Permission denied

Device is rooted, connected to system.

C:\Windows\System32>adb devices
List of devices attached
06a7b455        device

C:\Windows\System32>adb root
adbd is already running as root

Even adb shell doesn't work
127|root@android:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
mount: Permission denied
255|root@android:/ #

Have already referred these answers, but all of them have used mount successfully in some form or the other

[Android: adb: Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399028/android-adb-permission-denied)

[adb remount permission denied, but able to access super user in shell -- android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089694/adb-remount-permission-denied-but-able-to-access-super-user-in-shell-android)

Any help in changing the directory to rewrite?
Using a windows pc, device is samsung s4 mini

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089694/adb-remount-permission-denied-but-able-to-access-super-user-in-shell-android

Comment: Still doesn't work                                                              255|root@android:/ # adb root
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038 *
cannot bind 'tcp:5038'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
                                                                                        1|root@android:/ # adb remount
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038 *
cannot bind 'tcp:5038'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
1|root@android:/ #

Answer (score 0):

Using this command on adb

```
adb root
adb shell
mount -o rw,remount /
```

adb root is required to use the adb terminal as root

adb shell let you go type the command to access android system

last one for write permision