# How to set up static ip on Rasp pi3 running IOT?

Tags: adb, raspberry-pi3, iot, static-ip-address

I have a Rasp pi3 running IOT and I want to set up a static ip address. I want this because the pi is running a server. I have previously set up a static address by assigning it through the router. However, now I want to connect the pi to the network via a wifi extender, and the extender doesn't give the option to set up a static address.

Is it possible to set a static IP using ADB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Raspian stretch you must edit '/etc/dhcpcd.conf' file - you can find examples there
ie

```sh
# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
```

then restart interface or machine

Comment: Thanks, but can I access and edit this file through ADB?

Comment: I've been looking for a file named dhcpd.conf, but can't find it. I wonder if the ip address settings are in a different place with Android IOT? adb shell ls /etc lists all the files in /etc....

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399028/android-adb-permission-denied/15201460#15201460) will help?