# `adb pull /data/anr/...` returns `Permission denied`

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I want to get ANR traces from my Samsung A51.

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#pull_a_traces_file) tells to do `adb root`:

```
adb root
adb shell ls /data/anr
adb pull /data/anr/<filename>
```

But it does not work for my device. Why?
Or everyone assumes that developers have rooted devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it seems to vary device-to-device. Probably safe (enough) to say OEM-to-OEM.

On our LG test devices, you can just call

```bash
adb pull data/anr .
```

and go to town.

On our Google Pixels, you'd be met with "remote open failed: Permission denied", and `adb root` doesn't work without modifying or replacing the default `adbd` installation.

You can get around this by using:

```bash
adb bugreport
unzip bugreport-*.zip
rm bugreport-*.zip
cd bugreport-*
ls -lt FS/data/anr  # here they be
# also good stuff:
ls -lt FS/data/tombstones
```

Answer (score 3):

Did managed to get all reports with the `adb bugreport` command.

Comment: Holy crap, small world. I just now recognized your name from AL's GitHub issues xP